# Computer Science for the elderly

Tags: computer-science, terminology, language-theory

I learned C++ when it was C with classes. I find myself increasingly disliking new technologies like XML and Garbage collection.
On the other hand, I have discovered scripting languages like Lua and Python. And I find myself rather liking a hybrid environment of C++, with deterministic memory control, with an embedded script language, with garbage collection and all that entails.

My problem is, when attempting to learn these languages I find myself confronted with terminology that I just don't grok: lambdas, closures, etc.

What online resources are there for an older person to get current with this stuff?

Comment: Deterministic memory control is overrated.

Comment: @Mostlyharmless: right up 'till you run out, then it's underrated.

Comment: Donald (knuth) - is that you posting under a pseudonym?

Comment: One of my first projects was to port the C++ interpreter from AT&T SYS V to another Unix variant.  That was in 1985/86. If I'm not old, you can't be either. :-)

Comment: I suspect you have a lot of company on disliking XML.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) a long with the [attendant lectures](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/) provide a great introduction to functional programming (using Scheme) from whence many of these terms come.

Answer (score 8):

As much as it galls me to say it, [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org) is a great starting place. There are often detailed articles as well as links to other definitions on other sites, and examples on places like [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com).

It's also very worthwhile searching [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)!

Answer (score 6):

Stanford has some excellent computer science classes online

http://see.stanford.edu/SEE/Courses.aspx

Comment: I wish I could give you +100. Excellent link, thanks very much. I'm going to schedule an hour or two each week to watch a lecture.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a broader, in-depth  approach, take a look at MIT's OpenCourseware.

"MIT OpenCourseWare (OCW) is a web-based publication of virtually all MIT course content. OCW is open and available to the world and is a permanent MIT activity."

http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/web/courses/courses/index.htm#ElectricalEngineeringandComputerScience

Pertinent to your question, the "Introduction to Computer Science and Programming" course uses Python. There are also dozens of other courses offered, and many more at different institutions around the continent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to go through all that (rather theoretical) CS courses again. Just use wikipedia and look at the Python documentation. When it comes to modern C++ I suggest that you look at the C++ faq lite (just google it).